# JSON file load issue in angular2 with import

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to load local JSON file from asset folder with import module like below

```
import * as msgdata from "/assets/messages-eng.json";
```

imported into component and trying to console it as below.

```
console.log('msgdata data : ' + JSON.stringify(msgdata));
```

And i have added typings.d.ts file also as below

```
declare module "*.json" {
const value: any;
export default value;
```

}
But, I'm getting below error:
http://localhost:5557/assets/messages-eng.json.js 404 (Not Found)
But, My file is `"messages-eng.json"` only.
Please find below image fro error

[image]

Please help me on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have a json file, make a http-request to fetch it. if you don't want that, then just have a ts.file with a constant with your data that you can import.

Comment: Totally right exporting a constant from a .ts file should do the work in the best way I think

Comment: How to do that can you please explain with code example please

Comment: I did it but, I want from JSON file only without using http request. Is there any other way to load JSON file into component?

Comment: @GCP What is then wrong with importing a constant, if you do not want to have httprequest?

Comment: JSON file calling with http request will take time for laod. If load with import it will not take time to load file. So only iam asking this.